# Как правильно вывести дату и время как это делают в соц-сетях RedBean PHP

Tags: php, redbeanphp

вывожу данные через `R::findAl`. В данном случае вывожу дату, но не знаю как написать условия что бы к примеру если сегодня 24.06.2022 то показывало вместо этой даты, слово - Сегодня в ... Как это реализовать? Вот сам код:

```
    $posts_all = R::findAll('posts', 'ORDER BY -id');
                        
    foreach ($posts_all as $posts){
    echo '<span class="post-date">'.date('d.m.Y'.' в '.'H:i',strtotime($posts->post_time)).'</span>';
    }
```

А хочу примерно так: (Но так нельзя)))

```
$posts_all = R::findAll('posts', 'ORDER BY -id');
                        
foreach ($posts_all as $posts){
    echo '<span class="post-date">'.

    $date = date("Y.m.d H:i:s")
    if ($date == date('d.m.Y')){
     'Cегодня в ' .date('H:i');
    }

    else if ($date == date('d.m.Y', strtotime('-1 day'))){
     'Вчера в ' .date('H:i');
    }';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так:

```
foreach ($posts_all as $posts){
    echo '<span class="post-date">';

    if (date("Y.m.d") == date('Y.m.d', strtotime($posts->post_time))){
     'Cегодня в ' .date('H:i', strtotime($posts->post_time));
    }
    elseif (date("Y.m.d", strtotime('-1 day')) == date('Y.m.d', strtotime($posts->post_time))){
     'Вчера в ' .date('H:i', strtotime($posts->post_time));
    }
}
```

---

Если у вас $posts->post_time в формате `Y-m-d H:i:s` то можно так

```
if (date("Y-m-d") == substr($posts->post_time, 0, 8))
```

---

Но часто, как на stackoverflow, смотрят разницу в секундах между сейчас и временем поста

```
time() - strtotime($posts->post_time)
```

и пишут в секундах до 60 секунд, в минутах до часа....

Comment: Спасибо! А подскажите еще кое-что, проблема в том, что когда я вывожу любое условие по типу `if` в `echo` в `foreach` и пишу к примеру - `echo '<div>'.if (date("Y-m-d") == substr($posts->post_time, 0, 8)).'</div>'` - то мне выдает ошибку. Почему так? Я могу вывести просто к примеру `'<span class="post-date">'.date('d.m.Y'.' в '.'H:i',strtotime($posts->post_time)).'</span>'` , но не условия. Может у меня что-то не так с синтаксисом?

Comment: у вас в foreach вы водится echo, в конце которого стоит точка. Так  неверно. Оператор должен заканчиваться точкой с запятой. Я подправил код, тоже намудрил

Comment: Спасибо, всё понял!

Comment: Я могу задать еще один вопрос??? Он мне очень нужен! Как сделать что бы выводилось - "10 минут назад" или "1 час назад". Я просто смотрю на код, и экспериментирую в таком плане `if (date("d.m.Y", strtotime('-5 min')) == date('d.m.Y',strtotime($posts->post_time))){ echo 'Вчера в ' .date('H:i', strtotime($posts->post_time));}` - но оно работает криво (а точнее, весь день оно считает как за 5 минут))) Помогите пожалуйста последний раз!

Comment: я думаю вы легко нагуглите подобный скрипт в сети, что бы не писать уже много раз написанное. А как  делать - я вам написал - через разницу тайштампов

Comment: Хорошо, думаю нагуглю! И не такое находили xD